# add an image property to a domain class in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I have a domain class in Grails and I want to add a picture attribute (the image of the user) A detailed answer will be helpful for a Grails beginner like me.

What will be the type of the attribute? How can I store it in a database (MySQL)?

Comment: Est-ce ou quelque chose comme cela, vous cherchez? http://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented functionality like this in this way:

1. First of all domain class. I add 3 properties to the class where I can store byte array with image and image properties like image type (gif, png, jpg) and image original name.

   ```
   class User {
       byte[] image;
       String imageName;
       String imageContentType;

       static constraints = {
           image nullable: true, blank: true, maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20; //20MB
           imageName nullable: true, blank: true;
           imageContentType nullable: true, blank: true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Secondly, you need to remember to have proper type of form to upload image to your server:

   ```
   <g:uploadForm class="user-form">
       Image: <g:field name="userImage" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
   </g:uploadForm>
   ```
3. Thirdly, controller. 'create' action to get image from request and save it into database and 'getImage' action to get link to the image.

   ```
   class UserController {

       def create () {
           def imageMap = [:];
           def imageContentType = parameters.componentImageImageForm?.getContentType();
           if (imageContentType == null || !(imageContentType =~ "image/")) {
               imageMap.put("image", null);
               imageMap.put("imageName", null);
               imageMap.put("imageContentType", null);
           } else {
               imageMap.put("image", parameters.componentImageImageForm?.getBytes());
               imageMap.put("imageName", parameters.componentImageImageForm?.getOriginalFilename());
               imageMap.put("imageContentType", parameters.componentImageImageForm?.getContentType());
           }

           def newUser = new User(imageMap);
           def validation = newUser.save(flush:true);

           //if(validation == null) {
               //validation failed
           //} else {
               //validation passed
           //}
           //you can return here some msg or something you need
       }

       def getImage(Long id) {
           def user = User.get(id);
           if (user != null) {
               response.contentType = user.imageContentType == null ? "image/jpeg" : user.imageContentType;
               response.contentLength = user.image == null ? 0 : user.image.size();
               response.outputStream << user.image;
           } else {
               response.contentType = "image/jpeg";
               response.contentLength = 0;
               response.outputStream << null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the end, rendering an image in view (userId is of course id of user whose you want an image):

   ```
   <img src="${createLink(action: 'getImage', controller: 'user', id: userId)}"/>
   ```